# Why does boron fume in moist air? Is the following accurate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I initially guessed it was due to the formation of $\ce{H3BO3}$ but am now doubtful. Does it have anything to do with $\ce{HCl}$ formation? If the question referred to a boron halide, I could answer with that. Either the question is wrong, or my guess is. What's accurate?

I'd appreciate any help.
Grade 11 Chem.

Comment: Boron does not react with (moist or dry) air at room temperature. Do you mean ‘borane’?

Comment: If so, does my answer work?

Comment: If you're talking about boranes (simplest example $B_{2}H_{6}$), then the gas produced by reaction with water is hydrogen, and the boron containing product is $B(OH)_{3}$. I suspect most boranes would explode if you exposed them to oxygen though so not sure what experiment you are referring to.